# How add list(ArrayList) in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

how can I add a list from arraylist from a class created by me to a Jframe window?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one (of many) ways.

- Convert the `ArrayList` to a `Vector`.
- Construct a [`JList` using the `Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList%28java.util.Vector%29).
- Construct a [`JScrollPane` using the `JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28java.awt.Component%29).
- Construct the `JFrame`
- `JFrame.add(JScrollPane)`.
- `JFrame.pack()`.