# How to show ArrayList in JList

Tags: java, jframe

I am new in Swing. I am trying to show arrayList in jList. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: any code to share?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ArrayLists into JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269516/java-arraylists-into-jlist)

Comment: Similar to this closed non-question: [How add list(ArrayList) in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950956/how-add-listarraylist-in-jframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to bind ArrayList to JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420623/how-to-bind-arraylist-to-jlist)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: `new to JFrame`? UI framework where JFrame belongs to is named `Swing`. You should probably check [Swing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **java.util.ArrayList.toArray(T[])**. If you can provide some code I can give you some related answer to ur question try below code

```
JList jList = new JList(arrayList.toArray());
```

OR

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add("blabla");
aList.add("blublu");
aList.add("blibli");
aList.add("bleble");
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
for(String s:aList){
model.addElement(s);
}
JList<String> contactList = new JList<String>(model);
```

Comment: Now working actually I forgot to set the bounds of frame that's why. Thank you